# Лимит количество одновременных http запросов к серверу на Apatche/PHP?

Tags: php, http, mysqli, request

Разрабатываем Web api-сервис,где путем Rest запросов http на  серверную часть(php) будет производиться выборка из базы Mysql и возвращаться ответ клиенту!Помимо выборки из базы будет производиться сложная математическая логика php перед ответом!Вопрос таков,так как PHP якобы не является многопоточным,то сколько сервер может выдержать одновременных запросов,так как ответ с долгим временем выполнения?

И второй вопрос, оптимизатор наш хочет сделать финт с работой базы данных.Хочет Чтобы php постоянно держал базу открытой(перед окончанием лимита времени открытой базы репликация в др.базу)!То есть база постоянно открыта соединением,а при запросе от клиентов,будет тут же выполнятся выборка,и все якобы от одного коннекта,чтобы max_connections не было никогда,якобы одно соединение!Это возможно?

Comment: 1. Вы хотя укажите порядок цифр. Сколько обращений в секунду к беку? 2. Уже работает медленно, или хотите сразу все предусмотреть? Сильно сомневаюсь, что постоянное подключение к базе что-то принципиально изменит в скорости.

Answer (score 0):

1) Вас это не должно волновать, сервер сам разберется сколько потоков и процессов запустить для PHP. Нужно только чтобы хватало мощности железа всё это обрабатывать.

Часть ниже не соответствует действительности.

<s>2) скрипт php живет в пределах запроса, и умирает как только запрос завершен. так что это не лучшая идея. если вы хотите сделать демона на php то вам придется реализовать механизм обмена данными между вашим демоном и скриптом запускаемым из Apache
Есть подозрение что вы не совсем понимаете как именно происходит общение браузера с сервером так что перед такими решениями оптимизации советую разобраться более детально в теме.</s>

Comment: а вы, в свою очередь, возможно, не совсем в деталях знаете, как происходит общение пхп с БД, и что такое [постоянные подключения](http://php.net/manual/ru/features.persistent-connections.php)

Comment: Согласен, совершенно не знал про эту возможность =) убираю вторую часть ответа как неверную.

Comment: Подозрение,но не факт) Просто хотелось узнать,можно ли например на Java написать службу под линукс сервера,в этой службе обьявить слушателя от php!То есть цепочка клиент->php->Java->mysql,  где php будет в роли некоего прокси-который перенаправляет на Java-а там коннект к базе держится всегда!То есть  connection_max не будет никогда!

Comment: Можно службу, но как в комментарии выше сказано в этом нет необходимости, в php такой механизм есть из коробки =)

Comment: Только вот в конце статьи Пишут,что все равно количество одновременных соединений не победить(  !Вот  Например, если ваша база данных позволяет 16 одновременных соединений, и во время нагрузки на сервер 17 дочерних процессов попробуют открыть соединение, одна из попыток потерпит неудачу

Comment: @ALEX123 а почему бы просто не увеличить кол-во одновременных соединений, если будет таковая необходимость?
Я если честно тоже не понял плюсов от сего способа, кроме как очень коротких скриптов, которые делают 1 запрос и закрываются

Comment: )Вопрос стар как мир!Мощность сервера не позволит!

Comment: Вот тут не уверен, но имхо простаивающее соединение много ресурсов кушать не будет =) (не упираюсь по ресурсам пока что даже близко, не было необходимости тестировать)