# Как установить постоянное соединение с базой данных?

Tags: php, mysql, redbeanphp

Как установить постоянное соединение с базой данных? php 7.0, Библиотека для взаимодействия с базой данных redbeanphp

Comment: Что значит постоянно? Если ваш скрипт не прекращает работу, то и не разрывайте соединение. А если скрипт обрывается, то о каком постоянстве идет речь?

Comment: Скрипты выполняются разово, каждый раз идёт подключение к центральному файлу(правда не закрываются, но сам факт...открытие каждый раз происходит) мне под вебсокет нужно постоянное

Comment: @DmitryKozlov, на самом деле это не так, я сегодня был тоже удивлен что таковой режим(постоянное соединение) существует =)
В этом вопросе, в одном из комментариев есть указание на подобный механизм https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/883421/Лимит-количество-одновременных-http-запросов-к-серверу-на-apatche-php/883431#comment1438323_883431

Вот само указание http://php.net/manual/ru/features.persistent-connections.php

Comment: Для вебсокета есть Ratchet. Работает постоянно

Comment: да ладно? я его и использую. Но бл*** мне его надо с базой связать

Comment: сервер sql кикает вебсокет после продолжительного времени

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков я в курсе, хотелось подробностей, что имеет в виду автор

Comment: ```interactive_timeout=время
wait_timeout=время``` в my.ini увеличте

Comment: @Денис Лебедев насколько я знаю, работа с ними понижает стабильность. БД может в одностороннем порядке закрывать соединения, просто ошибка может произойти, при этом PHP будет ещё не один запрос тупить, и не восстанавливать соединение с БД. Стабильность гораздо дороже крох производительности - оптимизация производительности это 100 способов, повышение стабильности - только долгая работа руками. Но так было лет 9 назад, может сейчас всё и ок, попробуйте)

Comment: Есть вебсокет rather у него идёт проверка по базе юзера который совершил подключение, я смог сделать вариант с открытием и закрытием подключения для создания соединения, но сокет будет так-же получать сообщения для записи в базу, и что... каждый раз открывать и закрывать? если этого не делать- сервер падает с кодом 1000 хочу без постоянных переподключений к базе и при этом без изменением таймаута( это отсрочит проблему, но не решит её)